# Internal Server Error - Downloading attachments

Tags: 6, migrations

I've recently migrated a Drupal 6.22 site from my local host (Xampp 2.5) to a remote, shared server - Fasthosts hosting services.

After uploading the files through ftp and importing the database, I couldn't access the site at all - it would return a 500 Internal Server Error. Trawling the Drupal forums and searching online, I found out that this was down to the .htaccess file, which I subsquently removed.

This allowed the site to load, but only the homepage. I then found a .htaccess file in the Drupal forum which someone had edited and I uploaded that, which gave me full access to the site - good times! However, after performing a walk-through of the site, I've found that I cannot download any of the attachments I've uploaded to some of the pages.

Is this a .htaccess issue? I've trawled many forums and posted several questions around the place, but no one has given a response yet. My mate highly recommended StackOverFlow, so I hope someone can help!

I've checked the server logs and it's states the error is that the file is not found! But I've deleted and re-uploaded then several times now.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Problem solved!

There was another .htaccess file in the directory which held the attachments. Not sure whether is good practice or not, but I removed the file and hey presto, can now download the attachments!

Not sure if Drupal writes to this file or not (?!) only time will tell.

It's a quick fix, but a fix nonetheless! I'll spend more time researching this issue for future reference!

Comment: If you have found a solution, please create an answer to your question and mark it accepted, after the allotted time has passed, instead of posting it as a comment.  This will benefit both the site (by not having a question without an answer) and future visitors who have the same question to more easily find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal can put .htaccess files in some folders. It is likely that something in your Apache setup is different and the .htaccess files are no longer valid on your new server.

Removing the .htaccess file from the sub folder could leave you open to hacks, so it may be worth looking to see what it was trying to do and make sure that you are secure.

Comment: I deleted my .htaccess file form Drupal 6.22 package but I got same error